# Rounding when dividing integers Java

Tags: java

How to round a number in a big way in Java?
I have to get an answer z = 5.

```
int x=82; int y=20; int z;
z= x/y.
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided x and y are positive, add 1 less than the denominator to the numerator:

```
int x=82; int y=20;
int z= (x + y - 1)/y;
```